# Tizen Wearable Web App: Rotary event cancelling touch events?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm developing for a gear s2, and I have an app where I would like the user to be able to hold their finger on the screen while also rotating the bezel (concurrent rotary + touch events); however it appears that the rotary event handler overrides the touch event handler and triggers the `endTouchHandler`.

Rotary event handler added as follows:

```
var rotaryEventHandler = function(e)
{
   if (e.detail.direction === "CW")
   {
       console.log("Rotate CW");
   }
   else if (e.detail.direction === "CCW") 
   {
       console.log("Rotate CCW");
   }
}

document.addEventListener("rotarydetent", rotaryEventHandler,false);
```

Touch event handlers added as follows (code for handling touches is pretty much the same as examples online):

```
page.addEventListener('touchstart', multiTouchHandler, false);
page.addEventListener('touchmove', moveTouchHandler, false);
page.addEventListener('touchcancel', cancelTouchHandler, false)
page.addEventListener('touchend', endTouchHandler, false);
```

Looking into some log outputs, the rotary event doesn't cancel the touch event, it triggers the `endTouchHandler`.

No ideas on workarounds despite a bunch of tinkering... any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Just checked with a tizen native app and the behaviour is the same - rotary events trigger the finger_up event and cancel the touch operation...

Comment: Any updates in the meanwhile?